# concat two strings by sub-stringing with same length

Tags: java

I want to concat two strings, by sub-stringing each one with same length, and concatenation should happen like I mentioned below
for suppose,
I have str1 = raines, str2 = bowls, and LENGTH as 2, then my output should be raboinwless.

edit: *starting from leftmost alphabet, identify LENGTH number of letters from str1 and str2, and add the identified letters to output string respectively. repeat this until either str1 or str2 or both have less than LENGTH letters left. Add the remaining letters (if any) from str1 followed by remaining letter (if any) from str2 to output string.*

(first two letters from str1 is 'ra', and 'bo' from str2, concatenating them gives 'rabo', in next cycle the next two letters are 'in' from str1 and 'wl' from str2 by concatenating we'll get 'inwl', the total output now is 'raboinwl', at last we now have 'es' from str1, 's' from str2, the overall output is 'raboinwless')

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice 
{   
    //input str1 = raines
    // str2 = bowls
    // num = 2
    //expected output = raboinwless
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String instr1 = input.nextLine();
        String instr2 = input.nextLine();
        int innum = input.nextInt();
        String outstr="";       
        if(innum > instr1.length() || innum > instr2.length()) {
                outstr = instr1+instr2;
                System.out.println(outstr);
        }else if(innum < instr1.length() || innum < instr2.length()) {
            String[] chunks1 = instr1.split("(?<=\\G.{" + innum + "})");
            String[] chunks2 = instr2.split("(?<=\\G.{" + innum + "})");            
            int itrCount = 0;
            if(chunks1.length > chunks2.length)
                itrCount = chunks1.length;
            else itrCount = chunks2.length;             
                        
                for(int i= 0 ; i< itrCount;i++) {
                    outstr = outstr+chunks1[i];
                    outstr = outstr+chunks2[i];                 
                }
            System.out.println(outstr);
        }
    } 
}
```

- if I'm not making any sense or my way the questioning is bad, please comment or restructure my question,

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I found "take the mentioned length of the string from str1 and str2 and combine them, and do so forth, if for next iteration the length of first string or second string does not match, it can take the remaining characters and perform the concatenation" to be impossible to follow. I don't see how it works with the example, either.

Comment: Additionally, if you already *have* working code, this isn't the appropriate site for a question. You could *potentially* ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but you'd need the question to be significantly clearer.

Comment: not a free codereview site, if your code works, you shouldn'T be posting it in questions and answers website

Comment: What is your actual question? Your code isn't working or you seek for a cleaner way to implement the task?

Comment: my code is working, i wanna know how can i make it cleaner.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks i've posted my question there stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive version

```
public static String substringZip (String str1, String str2, int n) {
    if(str1.length() < n || str2.length() < n)
        return str1 + str2;
    else
        return str1.substring(0, n) + str2.substring(0, n) + substringZip(str1.substring(n), str2.substring(n), n);
}
```

Parameters

- str1 -> first String
- str2 -> second String
- n -> number of characters per cicle. if <= 0 Exception (check it in the main)